Implementation of planar graph max cut
http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/conferences/aussois2009/slides/pardella.pdf
Can you simply implement or pseudo code the content of this slide as a whole?

I'm not sure what the question is. Do you worry about copyright or intellectual property theft? Or whether it is actually doable?

Yes, you can. There is a preprint of the paper available for download (PDF) which likely contains all details you need.
It seems like they actually implemented the algorithm, so it could be possible to contact the authors and ask if they still have the source code. However, don't keep your hopes up, this was published 15 years ago.
